# Check result from command in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
mumodule a.version
```

When I run bash `a.sh`, it prints the result:

```
a_machine:
      2
b_machine:
      2
c_machine:
      1
```

I want to check in the `.sh` script that all the machines are with version: `2` and print `True`, otherwise `False`.

Is there any way to put the result in variable and check this output?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Combine infor from following 2 pages and let me know what did you achieve. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html

Comment: @grimsock: The problem is that I don't know the name of the machines

Comment: What exactly does `a.sh` do?

Comment: I should prints True if all the machine are with version `2` (and then exit) or false and then continue  to other steps

Comment: @MiddleWare, it is not clear how "The problem is that I don't know the name of the machines" follows from or relates to anything presented in your question.  Please clarify what scripts are run and what each one does if you want us to be able to help.

Comment: `awk '{ p = $1; getline; if ($1 < 2) {print p, $1}}'` either pipe it to it or run it with the output file as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.sh | grep "^ \+[0-9.]\+$" | grep -qv "^ \+2$" && echo False || echo True
```

What does it do?

First, runs your `a.sh` script.

Then, filters its output so that only lines starting with spaces and ending with numbers will continue. This is done by the first `grep` command.

After that, it checks if any of that filtered lines do not consist of the number 2 after the initial spaces. This is done by the second `grep` command.

Finally, if the previous `grep` command succeeded (at least one line did not have the number 2), it prints `False`. If it failed (all lines had the number 2) prints `True`.

Comment: It always prints true, even if the version is 30.1

Comment: Well, I was expecting versions to be only numbers, if it can contain dots, the regex must be different